# Move the Editor Box in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was searching around to find any solution to move the main editor box in WordPress 'Add New' page. I want to add two meta boxes between the title and the editor. Most of the methods I found on internet, use mostly depreciated wordpress hooks. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: I think the possible duplicate has the hooks you're looking for, and much better than the workaround you found. Hint: when you say you found a solution that doesn't work, post it with the question, it will lower drastically the chances of receiving -1. Oh, and +1 for sharing the solution ;)

Comment: Yea probably, I don't know why I couldn't find it earlier. Thanks anyways ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Solution. Replace 'post_type' with your custom post type ..

```
// Move TinyMCE Editor to the bottom
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'action_add_meta_boxes', 0 );
function action_add_meta_boxes() {
global $_wp_post_type_features;
if (isset($_wp_post_type_features['post_type']['editor']) && $_wp_post_type_features['post_type']['editor']) {
    unset($_wp_post_type_features['post_type']['editor']);
    add_meta_box(
        'description_section',
        __('Description'),
        'inner_custom_box',
        'post_type', 'normal', 'low'
    );
  }
add_action( 'admin_head', 'action_admin_head'); //white background
}

function action_admin_head() {
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .wp-editor-container{background-color:#fff;}
</style>
<?php
}

function inner_custom_box( $post ) {
  echo '<div class="wp-editor-wrap">';
  wp_editor($post->post_content, 'content', array('dfw' => true, 'tabindex' => 1) );
  echo '</div>';
}
```